# Deleted /tmp accidently

Tags: files, permissions, rm, root-filesystem, mkdir

Accidently, I ran `sudo rm -r /tmp`, is that a problem ?
I recreated it using `sudo mkdir /tmp`, does that fix the problem ?

After I recreated the directory, In the **places** section in the sidebar in nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 I can see /tmp , which wasn't there before .. Is that a problem ?

One last thing, do I have to run `sudo chown $USER:$USER /tmp` to make it accessible as it was before .. Would there be any side-effects after this ?

By the way, I get this seemingly-related error whenI try to use bash autocompletion

> bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/tmp` can be considered as a typical directory in most cases. You can recreate it, give it to root (`chown root:root /tmp`) and set `1777` permissions on it so that everyone can use it (`chmod 1777 /tmp`). This operation will be even more important if your `/tmp` is on a separate partition (which makes it a mount point).

By the way, since many programs rely on temporary files, I would recommend a reboot to ensure that all programs resume as usual. Even if most programs are designed to handle these situations properly, some may not.

Comment: `/tmp` doesn't need to have a partition, though it can be. `/tmp` can also be a filesystem of type `tmpfs` or `ramfs` keeping tmp files in memory. One needs to decide between ram or device depending on use, size of data, etc.

Comment: The final info is: `drwxrwxrwt   5 root root  4096 أغس 12 20:21 tmp/` .. Is that fine ?

Comment: @AmrAyman These are typical `/tmp` permissions, yes. `rwx` everywhere so that everyone can read and write to it, and a sticky bit (`t`) to ensure individual files ownership/permissions inside `/tmp`. [See here for more info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Answer (score 5):

The directory `/tmp` must have the permissions 1777 = rwxrwxrwt, i.e. everybody can read, write and access files in the directory, and (`t` = sticky bit) files may only be deleted by their owner. A lot of things will stop working if this isn't the case, sometimes in bizarre ways.

```
sudo mkdir -m 1777 /tmp
```

or

```
sudo mkdir /tmp && sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

`/tmp` must belong to root. Don't change its ownership to another user.

Programs that were using temporary files at the time you deleted them may be a bit confused. A few background programs keep a [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) in `/tmp` and will need to be restarted. The main one is the X server: after deleting `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, you will no longer be able to start any GUI application. You'll need to log out and back in to remedy that (fix the permissions first!).

Comment: is it not `chmod`?